# trying to do negative testing for paypal on their sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

how do i enable negative testing on the paypal sandbox?

I have found many old articles that suggest, you go to the dev dashboard click on the settings of a generated user and there is suppose to be a option for negative testing.

i have created 2 users plus the default user and none of them have the negative testing option in settings or anywhere else

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

What PayPal API are you testing? The setting in each [sandbox account options](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdashboard%2Faccounts) only applies to the old classic NVP/SOAP APIs, which you should not be integrating anyway.

With current REST APIs such as v2/checkout/orders, [request headers or test values](https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/negative-testing/request-headers/) are used to trigger negative responses in sandbox. No option needs to be enabled for this.

Comment: thanks preston, I did find those docs but i am using a 3rd party provider that isolates me from the api calls. That is why i was hoping i could use either a special user or CC

Comment: Depending on the integration, there are options for testing with cards https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing/#link-simulatecarderrors . If logging into a PayPal.com page, a random card from https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2FcreditCardGenerator&intent=developer should be used . You could add one to an account and then after adding it log into www.sandbox.paypal.com and change the address line 1 to one of the strings that triggers declines. I'm not sure why you would bother with such testing though.